# How to get all datasets that match a condition. NOT OUTTER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to get all teams that contain a certain dataset of mitglieder AND all other mitglieder's datasets in those teams.
For Example:

Team **A** got **Anna** and **Peter** mitglieder, Team **B** got **Anna**, **Maria** and **Johnny** and Team **C** got **Johnny** and **Mia**. If I want to find Anna then the output should look like this:

[image]
COUNT isn't important right now.

[image]

I tried this code, but this code gives me all datasets of mitglieder.

```
select teams.name, mitglieder.username, count(eintraege.eintrag_id) 
from (eintraege 
inner join teams 
    on eintraege.team = teams.team_id) 
right join mitglieder 
    on eintraege.mitglied = mitglieder.mitglied_id and mitglieder.mitglied_id = 101 
group by teams.name, mitglieder.username;
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i think
  on eintraege.mitglied = mitglieder.mitglied_id and mitglieder.mitglied_id = 101 
shall be 
 on eintraege.mitglied = mitglieder.mitglied_id 
where mitglieder.mitglied_id = 101

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub no that does not work. This way I get only those whose mitglieder_id is 101, but I want all mitglieder in that team. Not only 101.

Comment: select teams.name, mitglieder.username, count(eintraege.eintrag_id) FROM  eintraege 
LEFT JOIN teams on  eintraege.team = teams. team_id
LEFT JOIN mitglieder on eintraege.mitglied =mitglieder.mitglied_id
order by teams.name 

give this a try without group or you can group only with mitglieder.username but not team

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub that wouldn't work because of the COUNT() so I have to GROUP BY but if I GROUP BY mitglieder.username as you suggested it does not work either.

Comment: What count do you want?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f1955/5 see this and tell me what count you mean ? ??

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub [link] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3956db/1/0) COUNT gives you how many duplicates you got like if give the value to eintraege ('1', '1') twice you get 2

Comment: @lulk and what is the problem on the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3956db/1/0 ?

Comment: @JehadAhmadJaghoub I don't want to get Team C because it does not contain "Anna"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think this is your answer

```
select teams.name, mitglieder.username, count(eintrag_id) 
FROM eintraege 
LEFT JOIN teams on eintraege.team = teams.team_id 
LEFT JOIN mitglieder on eintraege.mitglied =mitglieder.mitglied_id 
where teams.team_id in (SELECT team from eintraege where mitglied = 1)
group by name, mitglied_id
order by teams.name
```

working example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3956db/3

Comment: yes also with count as i think distinct will not count duplication :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with mitglieder, then join to teams via eintraege to get the teams Anna belongs to as the basis of the query, then join back to the other tables again to create the output:

```
select distinct t.name, m2.username
from mitglieder m1
join eintraege e1 on e1. mitglieder = m1. mitglieder_id
join teams t on t.team_id = e1.team
join eintraege e2 on e2.team = t.team_id
join mitglieder m2 on m2. mitglieder_id = e2.mitglieder
where m1.username = 'Anna'
```

You haven’t defined what count you want, so I’ve left that out.

Comment: First, e2.username cannot work, you mean maybe m2. Any way when I run this I get all 414 rows mostly duplicate like more than 20 times.
Second, COUNT() is not important.

Comment: Now I get all teams and their members(mitglieder) but I want to get all teams and their members (mitglieder) that contains a specific member(mitglieder)

Comment: Now I get it I had to add to your third row this "and m1.mitglied_id = 101"

Comment: If you know the mitglieder’s id then start from mitglieder, but id’s are unreliable and shouldn’t be used/known outside the query. It’s better and more reliable to use public info, such as the username, for the lookup

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Have a nice day/night

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Syntax Because i havent try to run, but in this way you can try.

```
SELECT      TEAMS.NAME,
            EINTRAEGE_MITGLIEDER.USERNAME, 
            EINTRAEGE_MITGLIEDER.EINTRAG_ID
FROM        TEAMS TEAMS,
            (SELECT     MITGLIEDER.USERNAME, 
                        COUNT(EINTRAEGE.EINTRAG_ID),
                        EINTRAEGE.TEAM
            FROM        EINTRAEGE EINTRAEGE,
                        MITGLIEDER MITGLIEDER
            WHERE       EINTRAEGE.MITGLIED = MITGLIEDER.MITGLIED_ID
            AND         AND MITGLIEDER.MITGLIED_ID = 101
            GROUP BY    MITGLIEDER.USERNAME,
                        EINTRAEGE.TEAM) EINTRAEGE_MITGLIEDER
WHERE       TEAMS IN (  SELECT      EINTRAEGE.EINTRAG_ID
                        FROM        EINTRAEGE.MITGLIED = MITGLIEDER.MITGLIED_ID
                        AND         AND MITGLIEDER.MITGLIED_ID = 101
                     )
AND         TEAMS.TEAM_ID = EINTRAEGE_MITGLIEDER.TEAM
```